# How to print a matching group using sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to print yyy from this string

Tried this

```
echo "-foo bar -xxx yyy -blah 456 -gjk" | sed -n 's/-xxx [^]*$/\1/ p'
```

Got an error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: If I interpret this correctly you don't simply want _yyy_, what you _really_ want is "print the argument given to the '-xxx' option, whatever it is." Even if the options/args are in a different order: `-blah 456 -foo bar -xxx abc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "-foo bar -xxx yyy -blah 456 -gjk" | sed -n 's/.* -xxx \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

or with GNU grep:

```
echo "-foo bar -xxx yyy -blah 456 -gjk" | grep -Po -- '-xxx \K[^ ]*'
```

Output:

```
yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Awk (print the 4th column):

```
echo "-foo bar -xxx yyy -blah 456 -gjk" | awk '{ print $4}'
```

Whenever data seems to be divided into clearly defined columns, awk might be a better tool.